# RubyMotion for game development

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

How suitable RubyMotion for iOS game development?

I was not able to find CoreAnimation topics in documentation, but as I've heard someone was able to use cocos-2d with RubyMotion.

If you have some useful information which you are willing to share, I would greatly appreciate this!

Comment: Hi DarkDeny, although an interesting question, this might not most suitable for SO. Its hard to imagine what the "right answer" will look like as the answer will vary by each person's personal experience. Maybe the best place to ask this would be on ruby motion IRC channel or mailing list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to program your game completely programmatically, RubyMotion is a fine choice. There is no appreciable drop in performance and every C library and API is available to RubyMotion. Using motion-cocoapods you're even able to include CocoaPods and you can also include Objective-C libraries.

The one issue you may run into is a lack of RubyMotion-specific tutorials and documentation for games.

EDIT: I successfully (with help) recreated the Sparrow game engine demo in RubyMotion:

https://github.com/jamonholmgren/demo-sparrow

It runs beautifully.

Comment: Program your game programmatically?

Comment: As in, no XCode, no Interface Builder for menu screens, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can try JoyBox it combines popular 2D game engine for iOS, Cocos2D, folds in with Box2D physics engine, and wraps into Ruby API. Joybox can be found at this [link on github](https://github.com/rubymotion/Joybox).